# using VISP package for feature tracking in any types of image

Tags: ros, visp-auto-tracker, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi everyone,

as I checked the VISP pakage (http://wiki.ros.org/visp), in one of its applications, it uses the QR code as a template for feature tracking. Is it possible that instead of QR code, any other image be used? for instance picture of a building??

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/391442/using-visp-package-for-feature-tracking-in-any-types-of-image/) by [Delbina](https://answers.ros.org/users/74099/delbina/) on ROS Answers with karma: 109 on 2021-11-22

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The short answer is yes. You can use basically any picture to do object tracking. QR Codes are 'easier' to detect due to squarish structure/ black and white + they carry information that can be decoded so they can be used for multiple purposes.

If you want to use an image instead, then you can use for example Brute-Force Matching with SIFT Descriptors:
https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/dc/dc3/tutorial_py_matcher.html but that's one of many techniques used in Computer Vision.

[image: image description]

---

Originally posted by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) with karma: 1650 on 2021-11-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1